# Will a stateless component re-render if its props have not changed?

Tags: reactjs

One thing I had learned about React is that if the props to a component don’t change, then React doesn’t bother re-rendering the component. Is that true for stateless components too? Or do they behave more like “stupid” functions and get executed every time?

For example, if I had:

```
import StatelessComponent from '../StatelessComponent';

export default class DocumentsTable extends React.Component {
  state = {
    something: 'foobar',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.something }
        <StatelessComponent theOnlyProp='baz'>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

When `this.state.something` updates its value, does `<StatelessComponent>` get re-rendered? Or is it “smart” enough to see that its props didn’t change, like other React components?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### UPDATE 25.10.2018

Since React 16.6, you can use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) for functional components to prevent re-render, similarly to `PureComponent` for class components:

```
const MyComponent = React.memo((props) => {
  return (
    /* markup */
  );
});
```

Also, memo does [internal optimization](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/gaearon-patch-1/text/0000-memo.md#motivation).

> And unlike a userland memo() higher-order component implementation, the one built into React can be more efficient by avoiding an extra component layer.
>   Blockquote

---

### OLD ANSWER

**Yes, they always re-render <sup>1</sup> (unless you use React.memo as explained above)** if `setState()` is called in the component itself or one of its parents, because functional stateless components don't carry a [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). In fact, each React component is being re-rendered<sup>1</sup> unless they implement `shouldComponentUpdate`.

---

Important to note is that **calling** `render()` **doesn't mean that DOM Nodes are being manipulated in any way**. The `render` method just serves the [diff algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) to decide which DOM Nodes need to really be attached / detached. **Note that** `render()` **is not expensive, it's the DOM manipulations that are expensive**. They are executed only if `render()` returns different virtual trees.

From React's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#tradeoffs)

> Just to be clear, rerender in this context means calling render for all components, it doesn’t mean React will unmount and remount them. It will only apply the differences following the rules stated in the previous sections.

Just don't worry and let `render()` be called unless your component is huge, then you're better off with stateful Component that implements `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

Look [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5677) for an interesting discussion.

<sup>1</sup> means that `render()` function of the component is called, not that the underlying DOM node is being manipulated.

Comment: Thank you for the mention of `.memo`.  That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

See react does not only rerenders only If props are changed it even rerenders itself if any state change is there. In your case the component will rerender as your state is changing. The way react works is based on an algorithm named **Reconciliation**, what this algorithm does is that it compares your virtual DOM with real DOM and if it sees any change then it rerender your actual DOM by replacing it with your virtual DOM so any change in state will cause rerendering of the whole component.

Answer (score 1):

> Will a Stateless component re-render if its props have not changed?

Yes. **Stateless** render function will be called even if nothing has changed. However, React will in the reconciliation phase compare the virtual DOM (generated by the render function) against the existing DOM. This is far in the pipeline, hence not ideal if the render function was costly to compute.

A **Pure component** does have a default shallow comparison of the property and would have stopped the render to be executed. See the **Pure component** as a normal **class React component** that has a *shouldComponentUpdate* that compare with a triple equal the existing properties and the new one.

That being said, you can wrap your **Stateless component** into a **Pure Component** by using Recompose.pure (https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#pure) which will automatically perform, like the **Pure Component**, a shallow comparison without compromising on the short syntax of the **Stateless component**.

```
import StatelessComponent from '../StatelessComponent';   
const PureChildFromStatelessComponent = Recompose.pure(StatelessComponent);
// ... 
<PureChildFromStatelessComponent ... />
```