# Prevent rerender on function prop update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form with several layers of child components. The state of the form is maintained at the highest level and I pass down functions as props to update the top level. The only problem with this is when the form gets very large (you can dynamically add questions) every single component reloads when one of them updates. Here's a simplified version of my code (or the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/636xwz3rr):

```
const App = () => {
  return <Form />;
}

const initialForm = {
  id: 1,
  sections: [
    {
      ordinal: 1,
      name: "Section Number One",
      questions: [
        { ordinal: 1, text: "Who?", response: "" },
        { ordinal: 2, text: "What?", response: "" },
        { ordinal: 3, text: "Where?", response: "" }
      ]
    },
    {
      ordinal: 2,
      name: "Numero dos",
      questions: [
        { ordinal: 1, text: "Who?", response: "" },
        { ordinal: 2, text: "What?", response: "" },
        { ordinal: 3, text: "Where?", response: "" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const Form = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialForm);

  const updateSection = (idx, value) => {
    const { sections } = form;
    sections[idx] = value;
    setForm({ ...form, sections });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {form.sections.map((section, idx) => (
        <Section
          key={section.ordinal}
          section={section}
          updateSection={value => updateSection(idx, value)}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const Section = props => {
  const { section, updateSection } = props;

  const updateQuestion = (idx, value) => {
    const { questions } = section;
    questions[idx] = value;
    updateSection({ ...section, questions });
  };

  console.log(`Rendered section "${section.name}"`);

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "bold", margin: "24px 0" }}>
        Section name:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={section.name}
          onChange={e => updateSection({ ...section, name: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginLeft: 36 }}>
        {section.questions.map((question, idx) => (
          <Question
            key={question.ordinal}
            question={question}
            updateQuestion={v => updateQuestion(idx, v)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const Question = props => {
  const { question, updateQuestion } = props;

  console.log(`Rendered question #${question.ordinal}`);

  return (
    <>
      <div>{question.text}</div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={question.response}
        onChange={e =>
          updateQuestion({ ...question, response: e.target.value })
        }
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

I've tried using useMemo and useCallback, but I can't figure out how to make it work. The problem is passing down the function to update its parent. I can't figure out how to do that without updating it every time the form updates.

I can't find a solution online anywhere. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing. Thank you for any help you can offer!

## Solution

Using [Andrii-Golubenko](https://dev.to/changoman/react-optimizations-with-reactmemo-usecallback-and-usereducer-42ni)'s answer and this article [React Optimizations with React.memo, useCallback, and useReducer](https://dev.to/changoman/react-optimizations-with-reactmemo-usecallback-and-usereducer-42ni) I was able to come up with this solution: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/myrjqrjm18

Notice how the console log only shows re-rendering of components that have changed.

Comment: Because you pass in the same state variable through Hooks in all your Child components. All of them will end up updating when there's a change. To go around this you should create a state-variable and state-updating function for each child component.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: did you get any visible problem? I see your code looks fine and having key and props will help telling react to not render again if props are the same

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Use React feature `React.memo` for functional components [to prevent re-render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736983/will-a-stateless-component-re-render-if-its-props-have-not-changed/46737063) if props not changed, similarly to PureComponent for class components.
2. When you pass callback like that:

```
<Section
    ...
    updateSection={value => updateSection(idx, value)}
/>
```

your component `Section` will rerender each time when parent component rerender, even if other props are not changed and you use `React.memo`. Because your callback will re-create each time when parent component renders. You should wrap your callback in `useCallback` hook.

3. Using `useState` is not a good decision if you need to store complex object like  `initialForm`. It is better to use `useReducer`;

Here you could see working solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/o10p05m2vz

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much! If you are using React.memo and dispatch (which never changes) is there any reason to use useCallback?

Comment: @MichaelCox yes. You can't pass dispatch directly to the callback (e.g. `onClick`) so you need to wrap it into a function. If you don't use `useCallback`, your function will recreate each time when a component renders. This is causing unnecessary operations, such as deleting old function by the garbage collector, reassigning new function to a callback or rerendering your child component (if you pass this callback to child component).

Comment: "the dispatch context never changes, so components that read it don’t need to rerender" https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down

With normal callbacks you're absoultely right, but dispatch works differently. "React guarantees that dispatch function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list." https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: `React.memo` uses reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders. So it won't help if you pass a function as a prop. Instead, try `useCallback` in the parent component with dependencies `[ ]`. That way functions will be created only once.

Comment: Code using typescript:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-form-using-usereducer-1xjdd?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using life cycle methods to prevent rerendering, in react hooks example you can use, useEffect. Also centralizing your state in context and using the useContext hook would probably help as well.

Comment: please give your sample code so the questioner does not need to ask for clarifying. As mentioned in his post, he might have problems with using useCallback..

Answer (score 0):

laboring through this issue with a complex form, the hack I implemented was to use `onBlur={updateFormState}` on the component's input elements to trigger lifting form data from the component to the parent form via a function passed as a prop to the component.

To update the component's input elelment, I used `onChange={handleInput}` using a state within the compononent, which component state was then passed ot the lifting function when the input (or the component as a whole, if there's multiple input field in the component) lost focus.

This is a bit hacky, and probably wrong for some reason, but it works on my machine.  ;-)