# How to avoid unnecessary rendering in component with hooks

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have a themeprovider with two themes with the Emotion provider theme

and I have a component Header where I get this theme through useTheme:

```
const Header = () => {
  const Theme = useTheme();
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  console.log(Theme, 'this is header');
  const handleClick = () => {
    setText('');
  };
  return (
    <Container theme={Theme}>
      <Content theme={Theme} flexdirection={'column'}>
        <textarea
          onKeyPress={e => {
            if (e.key === 'Enter') {
              e.preventDefault();
            }
            if (e.key === 'Enter') {
              handleClick();
            }
          }}
          value={text}
          onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Digite aqui sua mensagem"
        />
        <Top theme={Theme} />
        <NavBar theme={Theme} />
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

and then I pass my theme as props for a child:

```
const NavBar = props => {
  console.log(props.theme, 'this is nav bar');
  return (
    <Nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#homex">test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#homexv">test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </Nav>
  );
};
```

But in this component I have a textfield where I will render when typing, but my theme is rendering together as in the gif:

[image]

here's my hook to control the theme:

```
export default function useAppTheme(defaultTheme = lightTheme) {
  const [theme, _setTheme] = useState(getInitialTheme);

  function getInitialTheme() {
    const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if (savedTheme === 'dark' || savedTheme === 'light') {
      return JSON.parse(savedTheme) === 'dark' ? darkTheme : defaultTheme;
    } else {
      return defaultTheme;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(theme.type));
  }, [theme]);

  return {
    theme,
    setTheme: ({ setTheme, ...theme }) => {
      if (theme.type === 'dark') {
        return _setTheme(darkTheme);
      } else {
        return _setTheme(lightTheme);
      }
    },
  };
}
```

and my principal component:

```
export default function App() {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useAppTheme();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('rendering app');
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <button
          css={css`
            background: red;
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 10px;
          `}
          onClick={() =>
            setTheme(
              theme.type === 'dark' ? { type: 'light' } : { type: 'dark' },
            )
          }
        >
          a
        </button>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, your code is working as expected. I think I can explain it as below.

`Header` is re-rendered because of state update (calling `setText` onChange). If a component is re-rendered, every child component will need to re-render (even if the props don't change). You can opt-out from this re-rendering using `shouldComponentUpdate` or being a `PureComponent` or `memoized function(al)` component. Here, as we can see `NavBar` is just a state functional component and it will re-rendered on every state updates. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46737063/4682365) for details.

You can solve this using `React.memo` like below:-

```
const NavBar = React.memo(props => {
  console.log(props.theme, 'this is nav bar');
  return (
    <Nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#homex">test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#homexv">test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </Nav>
  );
});
```

Now your component will not get re-rendered unless the props actually changed.